# C++ Templates with unique static members

Tags: c++, templates, static-members

a template class has all static members replicated for each instanciation of it. If I want a static member that exists only once for all instanciations, what should I do? Use a normal static field outside of the class template? Would work, but seems unelegant since there is no more association to the template class. Is there a way to somehow associate such unique static member with a template class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a template class has all static members replicated for each instanciation of it.

Nope. It has different statics for each *specialization*, but different specializations are different classes. Make no mistake about it, `vector<int>` and `vector<char>` are **totally** separate. Think of it as writing `IntVector` and `CharVector`.

EDIT: Don't use inheritance for this. Introducing a base class just so you can share a static member is definitely the wrong way to go.

If you want stuff shared between different classes, do it like you would usually do it. Wrap some statics in a third class and that's it.

Comment: While you're absolutely correct, note that you're not answering OP's question (they obviously did mean *specialization*).

Comment: I know, but there could still be some convenience members shared by them. Static members do not assume any notion of being a class anyway, so I don't have to care whether vector<int> and vector<char> are related classes or not.

Comment: @gexicide what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: for example, a static member that is the same for all specializations (and therefore, replicating it would be a waste of space)

Comment: "Wrap some statics in a third class and that's it". I don't see how that is a solution. He will not be able to access it by "vector<int>::myStaticMember". Inheritance seems to solve it nicely. Can you point out what precisely is "definitely the wrong way" about it?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb mornin`. Well, remember it's not just `vector<int>::myStaticMember`, but also `vector<char>::myStaticMember` referring to the same member. Does that still make sense, considering they're completely different classes? IMO, it doesn't. And deriving `vector` from a base class (that has no functionality, other than the common static member) is a missuse of inheritance. An instance manager is more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 5):

No; each template class is a completely separate object.

What you could do is create a common ancestor class with the static member:

```
class Parent
{
public:
  static int commonStatic;
};

template <typename T>
class MyTempl : public Parent
{
  static int nonSharedStatic;
};
```

Comment: You're suggesting using inheritance just for sharing a variable, right?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - The OP wants a variable shared between all specialisations of a template class, but tied to those classes. Off the top of my head, you could maybe do that by namespacing or inheritance; I can't see another way. Do you have one in mind?

Comment: I don't see why it has to be tied to the classes. The classes are completely separate, it doesn't make sense (from a logical point of view) for a single variable to be tied to multiple classes.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be tied to the classes. Suppose MyTempl was, in fact, MyList<T>; and Parent was actually MyList. Then it's clear that MyList<T> "is-a" MyList, and I might want to know how many MyLists I have, in total.

Comment: Also, regarding your list example, what exactly is the non-template `MyList` class? Is it actually a list? Does it hold any elements? (I don't think so)

Comment: Also, why stop here? Let's make `std::vector<T>` derive `std::vector`, because it's clear that `vector<T>` "is-a" `vector`. They have the same name, right?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't designed it fully yet. Perhaps a list wasn't the best example. But I could envisage, say, a pure virtual base class that offers common functionality, but can't be created without knowing the type of object it's designed to work on.

Comment: There we go! That's completely different. You have the base class because you want polymorphic behavior. Not because you want a common member, which most likely is wrong to be there in the first place.

Comment: All right then - in the better polymorphic case; why would it be wrong to have the static in question in the base class?

Comment: Well, you said "but can't be created without knowing the type of object it's designed to work on." which doesn't seem like a good base class for me. A base class rarely has to know about derived objects. That's the whole point. Having the static in the base class only makes sense if it is tied to the base class, not with the derived classes. So then the fact that the derived classes are templates doesn't even matter anymore.

Comment: This is actually a pretty decent use of inheritance. As long as you don't treat the derived classes polymorphically with virtual you won't have any calling overhead, and since there's just a static member in there, chances are high you'll get empty base-class optimization and add zero byte-overhead to each derived object :-)

Comment: Just tested it with gcc 4.7: there is indeed zero space overhead for the objects by doing this.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I think your assertion about logics is not sound. `basic_ios<CharT, CharTraitsT>` is a perfect example of how it makes sense to inherit from a common non-templated base (`std::ios_base`). They're mostly sharing all the format flag constants. Users don't care that they can also do `std::ios_base::hex`. They can do `ostream::hex`, because that's the class they are faced with when working with `cout`.

Answer (score 1):

Define some base class for the template class. Include in this base class all common members:

```
class ExampleBase {
public:
   static int foo;
};
int ExampleBase::foo = 0;

template <class A>
class Example : private ExampleBase {
public:
    static void setFoo(int f) { foo = f; }
    static int getFoo() { return foo; }
};
```

Then each of Example instances has the common static member `ExampleBase::foo`:

```
int main() {
    Example<int>::setFoo(7);
    assert(Example<float>::getFoo() == 7);
};
```

Comment: Why do you need to derive from ExampleBase? Why not just use it as-is?

Comment: @Luchian I do not understand you. As far as I understand question, there is a request for common static member for all object instances of all template instances of the given template. I do not know other solution. Please provide an example? See my update to the answer.

Comment: I meant that you can just access foo via ExampleBase::foo without deriving from it. & the question is wrong itself. Better than suggesting a solution that enables a serious design flaw, suggest a better design.

Comment: @Luchian OK - I see your point. Let see my next update. The it will be clear that using of Base class is necessary. I do not judge such design as wrong. Typical usage would be count all existing instances of Example<T> regardless of T.

Answer (score 0):

Put a global variable somewhere.

Something like this :

```
#include <iostream>

// header.hpp
extern int someValue;
template< typename T >
struct A
{
  int foo() const
  {
    return someValue;
  }
};

// source.cpp
int someValue = 5;

int main()
{
  std::cout << A< float >().foo() << std::endl;
  std::cout << A< int >().foo() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use a normal static field outside of the class template?

exactly; just plop it into a function outside of the template declaration.

if really want to restrict access in this scenario, you could use something like this:

```
class t_shared {
    static int& Shared() {
        static int s(0);
        return s;
    }
public:
    template < typename T >
    class t_template {
    public:
        void f() {
            std::cout << ++Shared() << std::endl;
        }
    };
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    t_shared::t_template<int>().f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't we define t_template as a friend of t_shared to avoid the unnecessary scoping?

Answer (score -1):

Class templates are actually a bit different from ordinary classes with respect to static members. The following is perfectly fine, even when `foo.hpp` is included by every translation unit:

**foo.hpp:**

```
template <typename T> struct TmplFoo
{
    static double d;
};

struct OrdFoo
{
    static double e;
}
```

**foo.cpp:**

```
#include "foo.hpp"

double OrdFoo::e = -1.5;
```

Note that we *never* need a separate definition of `TmplFoo<T>::d`. The linker knows how figure out that all local references to `TmplFoo<T>::d` (for a given `T`) refer to the same object.